# how can i return to page with same search filters

Tags: php, cakephp

In cakephp I can add search filters and change the post vars into Get as below. This works fine.
My problem is how do go to another page found from the list of searches and return to the same page? All search filters are gone  when i return as I am not storing them.

eg I search for invoice 2 and get a list of searches. i click on link from the search and view a page. I then want to return to the same page with same page number  for invoice 2?

if (($this->request->is('post') ||$this->request->is('put'))&& isset($this->request->data['filter'])) {

```
       $filter_url['controller'] = $this->request->params['controller'];
       $filter_url['action'] = $this->request->params['action'];
       $filter_url['page'] = 1;

// for each filter we will add a GET parameter for the generated url
foreach($this->data['Filter'] as $name => $value){
   if($value){
       $filter_url[$name] = urlencode($value);
   }
}   
//Post params are now GET paramaters
return $this->redirect($filter_url);    
   }//isset
```

Answer (score 0):

Options one: use link/button with [javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp) `window.history.back()`

Options two: use `Controller::referer()`  in your view like

```
echo $this->Html->link('Back', Controller::referer());
```

but this is only allow you to one step back.

Comment: it takes you back to the page with search filters as well?

Comment: this didnt work :Strict (2048): Non-static method Controller::referer() should not be called statically,

Comment: which is CakePHP version?

Comment: 2.5.x  I worked it out and used a similar line that works. Is there an issue with referer though?